# Try clause in While loop not executed after 1 loop

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

My java class. It has all the necessary packages. I'm using the command-line interface.

```
public static boolean checkLibIDPass(){
    boolean continueLogin = true;
    boolean check = false;
    boolean retry = false;

    while (continueLogin){
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String _id,_pass;
        int goBack;

        System.out.println("Input Librarian ID: ");
        _id = Sc.next();
        System.out.println("Input Librarian Password: ");
        _pass = Sc.next();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LibrarianFile.txt"));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && retry == false) {
                String[] values = line.split("\t",-1);

                for (int i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    if((_id.equals(values[0])) && (_pass.equals(values[1]))){
                        check = true;
                        retry = true;
                        System.out.println("Login Successful!");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(i == values.length -1){
                        System.out.println("Librarian ID or Password is invalid");
                        System.out.println("Retry Login?" + "\n" + "1 : Yes"+ "\n" + "2 : Choose another user");
                        goBack = Sc.nextInt();
                        if (goBack == 1){
                            retry = true;
                            continueLogin = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (goBack == 2){
                            retry = true;
                            continueLogin = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return check;
}
```

My output:

```
Welcome to Knowledgica's Library Management System !
Which type of user are you?
1 : Guest
2 : Librarian
3 : Admin
4 : Exit
2
Input Librarian ID: 
aasdasd
Input Librarian Password: 
asdasdasd
Librarian ID or Password is invalid
Retry Login?
1 : Yes
2 : Choose another user
1
Input Librarian ID: 
asdasd
Input Librarian Password: 
asdasd
Input Librarian ID: 
sdasd
Input Librarian Password: 
asdasdas
Input Librarian ID:
```

What I am aiming for is to access the try clause again if I wanna retry inputting another ID and Password. However, it always loops without the try clause.

Comment: Do you ever close the `BufferedReader`? I don't think so. Either close it within the loop, or take that line out of the loop so that you open the file once, then re-use the reader within the loop. Then close it after the loop. See if that helps.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to re-read the file if the log in is invalid.
Well this wont happen with you code as the while loop is inside the try, and the file read is outside the while.
you could have a 'validated' boolean and wrap the file read in a while(bool = false), then set the bool to true inside your current loop if the credentials are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[domsson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342869/3316645) greatly improves the readability of the code, but to answer the implicit question in the question title: (Why is the) "Try clause in While loop not executed after 1 loop"?

In fact, the try clause is executed again, but this is not apparent because the inner while loop is no longer executed. This is because you set `retry` to true in every case, and a condition on your inner while loop is `retry == false`.

Comment: Ah no wonder i should put the retry == false in the outer while loop so it resets every time.

Answer (score 0):

Comment turned answer. Not sure if this actually fixes your issue, I did not run the code.
There might be other issues. However, the ones outlined below should be fixed in any case.

---

Your code, heavily simplified:

```
public static boolean checkLibIDPass(){
    boolean continueLogin = true;
    boolean check = false;

    while (continueLogin) {
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String _id,_pass;

        System.out.println("Input Librarian ID: ");
        _id = Sc.next();
        System.out.println("Input Librarian Password: ");
        _pass = Sc.next();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LibrarianFile.txt"));
            /* Do lots of stuff */
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Note that you open a `BufferedReader` within the loop. If you enter the loop a second time, you try to open it again - on the same file! that's not a good idea unless you *closed* the reader previously. You should rather do one of the following:

1. **Close the reader** at the end of the loop
2. **Re-use the reader** by opening it outside of the loop

I recommend the second approach, as it should perform better. Now that we're at it, you can also take the `Scanner` out of the loop as well:

```
public static boolean checkLibIDPass(){
    boolean continueLogin = true;
    boolean check = false;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // create once
    String _id,_pass;

    BufferedReader br;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LibrarianFile.txt")); // create once
        br.mark(); // remember this position (beginning)
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (continueLogin) {
        System.out.println("Input Librarian ID: ");
        _id = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Input Librarian Password: ");
        _pass = sc.next();

        br.reset(); // go back to the beginning
        /* Do lots of stuff */
    }
    br.close(); // release the file
    sc.close(); // also best to close the scanner
    return check;
}
```

---

**One additional note:** Consider to further split up your method, so you end up with short and easy-to-read methods, where each one has a very limited, well-defined responsibility. It should make it easier to find bugs in the code as well.

Comment: I find it hard to split this code because its mostly loops in it and very specific to the task at hand. BTW, the BufferedReader br has to be in the outer while loop because I'm using br.readLine() in it. I forgot to write back br.close when I was searching for errors thanks for reminding.

Comment: Raika, how about you read in the text file at the very beginning of your program, save it into a `HashMap` or some other appropriate collection. This will make the lookup of id and password a lot easier and remove a loop in `checkLibIDPass()`. Then, how about splitting the method up such as one method fetches user input, another checks the input for being valid? The business logic can then be reduced to a few lines that will call into these two methods as often as is required.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that